# instance variable in iOS before ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

In ARC,all instance variables and local variables have a strong reference to the object they are pointing to by default.
I am trying to understand how MRR works and came across this example.
Consider the snippets below:

// CarStore.h
    #import

```
@interface CarStore : NSObject

- (NSMutableArray *)inventory;
- (void)setInventory:(NSMutableArray *)newInventory;

@end

// CarStore.m
#import "CarStore.h"

@implementation CarStore {
    NSMutableArray *_inventory;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)inventory {
    return _inventory;
}

- (void)setInventory:(NSMutableArray *)newInventory {
    _inventory = newInventory;
}

@end
```

//Back in main.m, let’s create and assign an inventory variable to CarStore’s inventory property:
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            NSMutableArray *inventory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [inventory addObject:@"Honda Civic"];

```
        CarStore *superstore = [[CarStore alloc] init];
        [superstore setInventory:inventory];
        [inventory release];

        // Do some other stuff...

        // Try to access the property later on (error!)
        NSLog(@"%@", [superstore inventory]); //DANGLING POINTER
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The inventory property in the last line in main method is a dangling pointer because the object was already released earlier in main.m. Right now, the superstore object has a weak reference to the array.

Does this mean that before ARC, the instance variables had a weak reference by default and we had to use retain to claim a strong reference ?

Answer (score 0):

Before ARC they were __unsafe_unretained by default. Weak was introduced along with ARC.